# Complex analysis - $f$is entire, $f(z)=u+iv$, for all $z\in$ Complex $e^{u(z)}<v(z)$, is $f$ constant? - proof check

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, density-function

I have answer of professor, but I want to check my proof, only to see if it right, if its not, I will just understand my professor answer ( no need to write answer ).
let us proof by contradiction.
suppose that $f(z)$ is not constant, thus by picard the image is dense.
Thus I Have $|f(z)-f(z_0)|$$<\epsilon $.
$|f(z)|=|f(z)+f(z_0)-f(z_0)|\le |f(z_0)|+\epsilon$
and since $|f(z)|$ is bounded, if $f$ is entire and blocked, so it is constant. in contradiction to my saying that it is not constant. Thus it is constant.
The problem with the proof that I did not use any of the info about $e^{u(z)}<v(z)$, which is very weird for me.
where is my logic of my proof goes bad? I guess the proof is maybe wrong, but since something from the basics of contradiction proof is bad.

Comment: Your title says $e^{u(z)}<v(z)$ but your post says $e^{u(z)}>v(z)$

Comment: oh dam, did not notice, sorry, the post is wrong. geetha understood that mistake I guess, since he answered correctly.  Will fix :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just get $|f(z)|<|f(z_0)|+\epsilon$ **for some** $z$, not **for all** $z$.

A valid proof: $|e^{(1+i)f(z)}|=e^{\Re (1+i)(u+iv)}=e^{u-v}<\frac 1 e$ because $1+u<e^{u}<v$. Hence, $(1+i)f$ is a bounded entire function.

Comment: oh, I see what you say. just to understand, if it was for all z, then the proof was good, right? 
Thanks, I guess I will just check my professor answer and try to understand it :)

Comment: Oh dam, did not see the edit. that proof looks awesome, wow, never though of it, Thanks!!!

Comment: Hi, just a small question if possible. if the case was $v(z)<e^{u(z)}$ instead of what I wrote at title and post. this is not a question I wanted, but since I wrote it at the beginning and fixed it, I tried to do it myself ( just for curiosity), I guess this way Taylor will not work, right? and is the sentence true? is it still constant if the equality is oposite?

Comment: @LearningToCode That looks harder, and I don't have an answer at this moment. Why don't you ask a separate question?

Comment: Ohh, I think I managed to solve it, was about to write :)
I used basically the fact that I can say $y>e^x$, thus the image is not dense, and if it entire and not dense, it is constant.

Comment: @LearningToCode That is right, but I was looking for a proof without Picard's Theorem. In my answer I have used just Liouville's Theorem.

Comment: Oh, if there is any other way without, it will be very good, yea
So I will open a new post? Edit: I will open now :)