# Complex analysis - $f$is entire, $f(z)=u+iv$, for all $z\in$ Complex $e^{u(z)}>v(z)$, prove $f(z)$ is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

this is a question I asked two days ago, but in a different way of equation.
[Complex analysis - $f$is entire, $f(z)=u+iv$, for all $z\in$ Complex $e^{u(z)}<v(z)$, is $f$ constant? - proof check](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4764465/complex-analysis-fis-entire-fz-uiv-for-all-z-in-complex-euzv/4764467?noredirect=1#comment10120201_4764467)
But this question, is basically the other way around of inequality.
There is a way to solve it using Picard theorem.
But I wish to find it any other way using less complicated ways ( like how to solve the inequality but the other way, using Taylor and Liouville ).
Using Picard, you solve it this way:
From the given, you can understand that $e^x<y$, thus the image is not dense ( since you cant find a ball underneath the domain ), and thus by Picard, $f(z)$ is entire and the image is not dense, thus it is constant.
But I would like to know if it possible without using Picard.

Comment: This answer https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4764467/42969 to your previous question uses only Liouville's theorem to prove that $f$ is constant.

Comment: Yea, but notice the equality is different, the opposite way, it is not the same question
@MartinR it will not work here
I tried doing this using some sort of functions, but could not make it work, since we dont have an inequality instead of Taylor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Idea:* If all values $f(z)$ are below the curve $v = e^u$ then $f$ necessarily omits some disk in the upper half-plane.

*Concretely:* For all $z \in \Bbb C$ is either
$$
 |u(z)| > \frac 12
$$
or
$$
 |u(z)| \le \frac 12 \implies v(z) < e^{u(z)} \le e^{1/2} < 2 \, .
$$
This shows that $f$ does not attain any values in the disk with radius $1/2$ and center $3i$. In other words,
$$
 |f(z) - 3i | \ge \frac 12 \implies \frac{1}{|f(z) - 3i |} \le 2 \, .
$$
By Liouville's theorem, $1/(f-3i)$ is constant, which means that $f$ is constant.

*Sketch:* Created with [GeoGebra](http://www.geogebra.org/)
[image]

*More generally:* $\{ u+iv \mid  v > e^u \}$ in a nonempty open subset of $\Bbb C$, therefore it contains some disk $B_r(w_0)$. $f$ does not attain any values in $B_r(w_0)$ so that $1/(f-w_0)$ is bounded and therefore constant. (That is essentially the proof of the [Casorati–Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casorati%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).)

Comment: Wait, from where did that $\frac 1 2$ come from? also the disk with radius $\frac 1 2$ and center $3i$, what is the thinking behind it? why did you do it? please explain to me :(

Comment: I mean, what is the thing that popped your mind into thinking this? was there any before thinking \ sketches or something? I am trying to think how to think like that + still understand the solution.

Comment: @LearningToCode: I have added the idea and a sketch.

Comment: Hi, yea I just saw. my last problem is regarding the $\frac 1 2$, you have two options, one for bigger and one for smaller equal. I am trying to understand what happens at bigger, $\frac 1 2 <|u(z)|$. it is outside the ball, so it is irrelevant?

Comment: Oh, I think I maybe managed, I will try to think it further, thank you very much!!

Comment: If $|u(z)| > 1/2$ (the light green area) then $f(z)$ is outside the red disk. And if $|u(z)| \le 1/2$ then $v(z) < 2$ (the blue area) so that again $f(z)$ is outside the red disk.

Comment: Yea, it is actually a very good thinking, will try to make it further into other questions also :)

Comment: @LearningToCode: I have added another (more general) argumente, which can be used here and also for your previous question.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the investment to help :) helps a lot ( test in 2days :) ).................... And yea, it actually looks like that...... Just a small questions in regards to that: if $f$ does not have any values at $B_r(\omega_0)$, why is that bounded? I see so at the proof at wiki they say it. EDIT: sorry, was stupid for a moment :) Understood. wanted to make sure I understand and found that proof for that sentence :)